# Editable time-picker issue alert message is coming after update value

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, datatables, jeditable

Currently devloping editable datatable with **jeditable.js** in datatable i put timepicker in jeditable datatable that shows hours and minute dropwdown box. when i update the value it update in datatabase but when i return value in string it shows my new value in **alert box** and **datatable is not updated.**

**datatable works perfectlly with type=text,textarea,select but not with timepicker**

**here is my timepicker code that i put in jedtiable.js**

```
 time: {
                element: function (settings, original) {
                    var hourselect = $('<select id="hour_"><option selected value="">HH</option>');
                    var minselect = $('<select id="min_"><option selected value="">MM</option>');

                    /* Hour loop */
                    for (var hour = 1; hour <= 12; hour++) {
                        if (hour < 10) {
                            hour = '0' + hour;
                        }
                        var option = $('<option>').val(hour).append(hour);
                        hourselect.append(option);
                    }
                    $(this).append(hourselect);

                    /* Minutes loop */
                    for (var min = 1 ; min <= 60; min++) {
                        if (min < 10) {
                            min = '0' + min;
                        }
                        var option = $('<option>').val(min).append(min);
                        minselect.append(option);
                    }
                    $(this).append(minselect);

                    /* Hidden input to store value which is submitted to server. */
                    var hidden = $('<input type="hidden">');
                    $(this).append(hidden);
                    return (hidden);
                },
                /* Set content / value of previously created input element. */
                content: function (string, settings, original) {

                    /* Select correct hour and minute in pulldowns. */
                    var hour = parseInt(string.substr(0, 2), 10);
                    var min = parseInt(string.substr(3, 2), 10);

                    $('#hour_', this).children().each(function () {
                        if (hour == $(this).val()) {
                            $(this).attr('selected', 'selected');
                        }
                    });
                    $('#min_', this).children().each(function () {
                        if (min == $(this).val()) {
                            $(this).attr('selected', 'selected');
                        }
                    });

                },
                /* Call before submit hook. */
                submit: function (settings, original) {
                    var value = $("#hour_").val() + ":" + $("#min_").val();
                    $("input", this).val(value);
                }
            }
```

after submiting the data to server the value is update on server-side correctly but when i return value this function shows error

```
function _fnShowError(errorText, action)
{
    alert(errorText);
}
```

please guide me what can i do to solve this error

please also tell me which is the best datatable for inline editing

**Note: I am new in this.**